# Azure : CustomLog Configuration

Tags: azure

I am trying to configure Azure Customlog through template or az ut it seems that it is not yet possible. I have tried using "Microsoft.OperationalInsights" API where in you can povide CustomLog as kind of datasource. But there I cannot find any mention of properties which I need to define here . I don't know why but earlier I have read a page configuring customLog data source but now I am not able to find it anywhere

Is there is any way I can configure custom Logs pro grammatically or collect customLogs from my linuxVM without using a third party tool??

If nothing works then I will bundle all my logs and put them on a blob storage but my client is adamant to use LogAnalytics or any other Azure service.

Update : API version in which CustomLogs are defined is '2015-11-01-preview' not able to find schema also for this version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching I got that details from this link:
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/commit/75113c9981ddf444f58cb48d7224f529f0dcfbdb#diff-8d43b41f72b1a3b8ec4c4d17a92f7424L66